# Fixing mac bootcamp boot to windows after formating a disk

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, imac, startup, dual-boot

I have an old iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011) and I wanted to give it a new life with a new SSD. I've installed both Mac & Windows on the SSD and life was good.

Then I decided to format the old HDD to exFat as to use from both Mac & Windows, and now it won't boot to Windows anymore, even though Windows partition was untouched on the SSD.

I think even though it's installed & run Windows on the SSD, it was somehow using the boot from the old bootcamp instalation I had on the HDD. Now that it's removed I get `No bootable device` error when trying to startup in bootcamp using the Startup disk setting.

Startup disk app with non-working bootcamp:
[image: startup disk app with non-working bootcamp]

Any advice on how I could recover it withouth a new Windows instalation?
If it helps I'm not shy to use terminal commands or create other boot disks.

Disks setup:
[image: disk]

New SSD with working Mac, and non-working Windows installation:
[image: New SSD with working Mac, and non-working Windows installation]

Old HDD that was formatted:
[image: Old HDD that was formatted]

Comment: What happens if use a MBR partitioning scheme on the internal HDD?

Comment: Haven't tried it. Also a bit hard to test as would have to make space for a few humdred gb on the ssd to re-fromat.
What should I expect on chamge?

Comment: Ok, then hybrid partition the internal HDD. This does not require reformatting. Since Windows was working before you decided to format the old HDD to ExFAT, I was guessing the old HDD was hybrid partitioned. You now show the HDD as having GUID Partition Map and I am guessing the HDD is no longer hybrid partitioned. I am guessing the loss of the hybrid partitioning on the HDD may be causing a failure of Windows to BIOS boot from the SSD.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I've eventually cleared the HDD and set it up as Master Boot record, but still didn't boot. Also something to mention, if I press `alt/option` key, in the boot options I only have mac. Bootcamp boot only visible in the restart menu mentioned above.

Comment: If you had a BIOS booting Windows installed on both the HDD and SSD before erasing the HDD and Windows was booting from the HDD as you have suggested, then I think you should have encountered the Windows Boot Manager. Do not mention this anywhere in your question. The Windows Boot Manager would have a menu allowing you to select which Windows you wanted to use.

Comment: Can you post the output from `cd /Volumes/BOOTCAMP;ls -d bootmgr boot boot/BCD`? Here I assume Windows is installed on the SSD to the volume labeled `BOOTCAMP`. If your label is different, then make the appropriate substitution.